# Flickering in Chrome (but not Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome

In google chrome parts of [webpages](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z04-3zd6AYk), images and [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miRYkOKupoA) are flickering. This does not happen in [firefox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5RIa4M5fIQ). Sometimes when I change tabs, I see [bits of other tabs overlayed on the current tab](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1x9gC3hEb82TmFSRktJZFd1SnM/view?usp=sharing). I also get [flickering when I type in the address bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0X6wUr_n3UY).Has anyone else encountered this? It seems like some sort of graphics card problem, but I have been using the onboard Intel graphics with this machine for 5+ years with no issues. Only in the last few months has this flickering started. The issue even persisted after reinstalling Ubuntu (got a new hard drive so I did a clean installation).

I have tried the solutions from these two askubuntu questions:

- [Youtube videos flickering in chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481532/youtube-videos-are-flickering-on-chrome)
- [Google Chrome "flickering"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279088/google-chrome-flickering)

**System Info:**

[image: System Information]

**Chrome Version:**

Version 43.0.2357.125

**Contents of chrome://gpu**

[image]

Comment: Eventually I solved this problem, or at least I worked around it. I discovered that the flickering never began until I opened an instance of gVim. When I open gVim, the screen goes black for a second, as if my graphics driver is being modified, and then it comes back on. Afterwards when I use chrome the screen flickers.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. Try disabling 'Use hardware acceleration when available' option in settings. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that and it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this on Ubuntu yet but in windows the solution was:

1. go to `chrome://flags/`
2. go to `Hardware-accelerated video decode Mac, Windows, Chrome OS`

   **Hardware-accelerated video decode where available**

   `disable-accelerated-video-decode` **Enable**

   make it disabled .